# UIKeyboard stops working randomly

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uikeyboard

when typing into a searchBar, 80% of the time it works fine, however the rest of the time, when I press a letter nothing happens, it is as if the keyboard stopped working.

Any thoughts?

Comment: show us some code! way too hard to help otherwise

Comment: Ok, I found that it happens when I create a SVProgressHUD.m call, specifically, show with message. I think it disables the searchbar

Comment: Ended up temoving SCprogressHUD. Not sure what it did, but after loading a message with it it diaabled my search controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVProgressHUD was causing the issue (third party activity indicator). I disabled it.